# iPhone app link : AppStore + Website or only Website

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks

I'm currently redesigning my personal web site and I want to link to my different iOS apps. I have currently two links for each of my apps : Website and AppStore.

But is the AppStore link is really necessary? We are making web sites for iOS apps to describe it in a better fashion then we can do on the AppStore itself. So why link to the AppStore.

I understand there will be people wanting to go to the AppStore directly, they will have 2 links to click. Is worth it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about only app store? The App store page has a description, reviews, and the ability to download the app. Not to mention I have found this to be common practice.

If you really think the website for these is amazing and describes it much better, than go for it. But I think you will find users appreciate just getting to business and going to the apps store page.

Comment: +1) My thoughts exactly. Why bother to "brag even more" if the user is ready to go for it...

Comment: I get the point and I may do that (I'll look at the traffic of my current web site). The main problem I see here is that I get a lot of support request from my site (even with a built-in support module in my app).

Comment: Note that Apple, themselves, encourage you to have a web page for your app. That, of course, is not a UX requirement, but rather an Apple requirement.

Comment: Just accepted your answer, I've decided to don't make an app web site. On my AppStore page I will point to my personal web page and I special support page I'll make.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider to create a clearer seperation between the two choices. On your current page, they look almost the same and the user must think twice before deciding what to do.  Create a bigger main icont hat takes you to the web-site and a smaller and clearer "take me directly to appstore" ikon that people can use. If the user wants to try it out, they will look for the shortcut immedeatly.

Remember to have an clear appstore button an the web page as well. Users that clicks the first and best should also find the appstore button right away on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Use a link to your site for it, and within that site have a link to the AppStore.

I think the way that you have done it on your site(not your link here, but on [here](http://littlekiwi.co.cc/LittleKiwi/LittleKiwi.html) is great. You have the description, which could easily overlap with what is offer on the AppStore link, **but what is key here is your movie that shows the actual app in action**, along with the little dot that simulates your finger moving through the application(very clever).

If they like what they see and want more, they click the AppStore icon. Without having this movie I would agree with Jon and say just go for the AppStore  link, but the video you provided is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

giving this answer without having found your personal website. (The name of your startup appears besides your own name everywhere online)

In general, you own an amount of mobile applications and now what?
First of all, I understand the need to present them somewhere, at your own online space to clarify the ownership and that this should be added to one more thing you have done in your life. If this was the only reason for displaying them, then just putting them all together in a list or any other similar format then why bother making it more complex?

However, if you have a specific audience in your mind and for what reasons this audience is visiting your personal website then you might consider alternative designs.
For example, if you own an awesome mobile application that would be interesting to your audience why not put it in a large section that covers the entire available width and have the rest underneath to occupy a much smaller screen real estate each. Other ideas could be valid always depending on the audience. So more information on whom you optimize for, would be necessary to elaborate.

Now if you don't have time for doing major changes and you are only concerned with the choice of the link then I would go with the App Store link because the user probably already knows what to expect, where to find the information that he is looking for etc. Unless the website for this mobile application tends to load faster and provides the most important information above the fold.